# GitLab job allow failure on certain exit code

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab CI/CD job doing some stuff.

I want some executed commands to be able to fail and result in a warning for this job, but I also want other command to result in an error in the pipeline if they fail.

I have set in the .yaml file `allow_failure: true`, which will always result in a warning for this job regardless of the error.

Can I tell GitLab job to output an error for a specific exit code and a warning for another ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With gitlab 13.9 `allow_failure:exit_codes` were [introduced](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure). With that you can now allow failure for certain exit codes and fail the job for all other ones.

```
  allow_failure:
    exit_codes:
      - 137
      - 255
```